# is there a special way to put an input field of type checkbox inside a tabledata tag of a table that is present inside an angularjs modal?

Tags: html, angularjs

here is my modal:

```
                    <!-- modal for viewing permissions -->
                <div id="modal-user-permissions" class="modal">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <h4 id="modal-user-title">User Access permissions</h4>
                        <div class="row">
                            <table class="hoverable bordered">

                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="text-align-center">Allow?</th>
                                        <th class="text-align-center">Page Id</th>
                                        <th class="width-30-pct">page Name</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody >
                                    <tr ng-repeat="d in pages| filter:search">
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="d.selected"/></td>
                                        <td class="text-align-center">{{ d.page_id}}</td>
                                        <td>{{d.page_name }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                            <div class="input-field col s12">


                                <a id="btn-update-user" class="waves-effect waves-light btn margin-bottom-1em" ng-click="updateUser()"><i class="material-icons left">edit</i>Save Changes</a>

                                <a class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-light btn margin-bottom-1em "><i class="material-icons left">close</i>Close</a>
                            </div>
```

for testing i'm passing true in every d.selected . i'm not getting the checkbox

here is the output:

**Output**

[image]

i would like to know if i'm not doing something correctly. Any best practices would be appreciated. and finally please tell me a way to get that check box bellow the allow heading in the output table included as picture.

Comment: Can you please add a working example (plunkr, codepen, or the stackoverflow HTML\CSS\JS snippet)? it will help a lot to give you an answer

Comment: sorry @Thatkookooguy i tried but the code is linked to database on local host ... doesnt make sense

Comment: You can create a copy of the UI without an actual database.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ngChecked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) instead on ngModel.

> Sets the checked attribute on the element, if the expression inside
>   ngChecked is truthy.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="d.selected"/>
```